# Temporary tables bloating pg_attribute

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm using `COPY` to insert large batches of data into our database from CSVs. The insert looks something like this:

```
-- This tmp table will contain all the items that we want to try to insert
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_items
(
    field1 INTEGER NULL,
    field2 INTEGER NULL,
    ...
) ON COMMIT DROP;

COPY tmp_items(
    field1,
    field2,
    ...
) FROM 'path\to\data.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);

-- Start inserting some items
WITH newitems AS (
    INSERT INTO items (field1, field2)
    SELECT tmpi.field1, tmpi,field2
    FROM tmp_items tmpi
    WHERE some condition

    -- Return the new id and other fields to the next step
    RETURNING id AS newid, field1 AS field1
)
-- Insert the result into another temp table
INSERT INTO tmp_newitems SELECT * FROM newitems;

-- Use tmp_newitems to update other tables
etc....
```

When will then use the data in `tmp_items` to do multiple inserts in multiple tables. We check for duplicates and manipulate the data in a few ways before inserting, so not everything in `tmp_items` will be used or inserted as is. We do this by a combination of CTEs and more temporary tables.

This works very well and is fast enough for our needs. We do loads of these and the problem we have is that `pg_attribute` is becoming very bloated quite fast and autovacuum doesn't seem to be able to keep up (and consumes **a lot** of CPU).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to perform this kind of insert without using temp tables?
2. If not, should we just make autovacuum of `pg_attribute` more agressive? Won't that take up as much or more CPU?

Comment: You could get rid of the temp table completely and map the CSV file as a foreign table using the [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) foreign data wrapper

Comment: Stab in the dark, but does your database have any [logical replication slots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/view-pg-replication-slots.html)? I've had problems in the past with autovac choking on catalog tables (`pg_attribute` in particular) because some orphaned logical slot still needed them.

Comment: @NickBarnes Not that I know of. I can do a manual `VACUUM FULL` to get rid of the dead rows. Just seems that the autovacuum won't remove them all

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I over simplified a little bit. In another part of the application we also use `FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)` as well as from CSV, so I guess that wouldn't work in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution would be that you create your temporary tables at at session start with

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... (
   ...
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Then the temporary tables would be kept for the duration of the session but emptied at every commit.

This will reduce the bloat of `pg_attribute` considerable, and bloating shouldn't be a problem any more.

You could also join the dark side (be warned, this is unsupported):

- Start PostgreSQL with

  ```
  pg_ctl start -o -O
  ```

  so that you can modify system catalogs.
- Connect as superuser and run

  ```
  UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_class
  SET reloptions = ARRAY['autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=0']
  WHERE oid = 'pg_catalog.pg_attribute'::regclass;
  ```

Now autovacuum will run much more aggressively on `pg_attribute`, and that will probably take care of your problem.

Mind that the setting will be gone after a major upgrade.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try that. How will this work with concurrency, connection pools and things like that? Will I risk reusing the same table (and dropping rows) between different inserts?

Comment: Yes, and that will require some thinking to get it right. But since the table is emptied at the end of each transaction, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Ok, great. I'm thinking that adding some kind of generated transaction id   column to the temp table should cover that then

Comment: Don't forget that there is also `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: I've been thinking about this. If the rows are deleted when the transaction is commited. Then the rows of another transaction that uses the same temp table would be deleted as well? That seems like a big problem possibly. Or will there never be two transactions using the same temp table at the same time? Thank you for helping with this issue :)

Comment: Every session has its own private temporary table; they are never shared. Since one database session can have only one database transaction at a time, there is no problem.

Comment: Ok, sounds good! But then I wonder what you where referring to in your first comment: "Yes, and that will require some thinking to get it right..."?

Comment: I mean in connection with connection pooling. You have to create the temporary table when the database connection is established, but not when you get a session from the pool.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I was little confused there :) But that shouldn't be a problem if I use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in the query I run in the transaction I guess

Comment: Yes, I agree. It should be easy to handle.

Comment: Alright! I'll give it a try. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe does ON COMMIT DROP have the same effect as ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS ?

Comment: @SirajMansour No.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe wow quite a niche finding here, who would've thought ON COMMIT DROP isn't as effective in reducing bloat of pg_attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but somebody might find my help useful here in the future.

So we're very heavy on temp tables having >500 rps and async i\o via nodejs and thus experienced a very heavy bloating of pg_attribute because of that. All you are left with is a very aggressive vacuuming which halts performance. 
All answers given here do not solve this, because droping and recreating temp table bloats pg_attribute heavily and therefore one sunny morning you will find db performance dead, and pg_attribute 200+ gb while your db would be like 10gb.

So the solution is elegantly this

```
create temp table if not exists my_temp_table (description) on commit delete rows;
```

So you go on playing with temp tables, save your pg_attribute, no dark side heavy vacuuming and get desired performance.

don't forget

```
vacuum full pg_depend;
vacuum full pg_attribute;
```

Cheers :)