# Bloating of pg_attribute caused by repetitive temporary table creations

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a process which is creating thousands of temporary tables a day to import data into a system.

It is using the form of:

```
create temp table if not exists test_table_temp as
select * from test_table where 1=0;
```

This very quickly creates a *lot* of dead rows in pg_attribute as it is constantly making lots of new columns and deleting them shortly afterwards for these tables. I have seen solutions elsewhere that suggest using `on commit delete rows`. However, this does not appear to have the desired effect either.

To test the above, you can create two separate sessions on a test database. In one of them, check:

```
select count(*)
from pg_catalog.pg_attribute;
```

and also note down the value for n_dead_tup from:

```
select n_dead_tup
from pg_stat_sys_tables
where relname = 'pg_attribute';
```

On the other one, create a temp table (will need another table to select from):

```
create temp table if not exists test_table_temp on commit delete rows as
select * from test_table where 1=0;
```

The count query for `pg_attribute` immediately goes up, even before we reach the commit. Upon closing the temp table creation session, the `pg_attribute` value goes down, but the `n_dead_tup` goes up, suggesting that vacuuming is still required.

I guess my real question is have I missed something above, or is the only way of dealing with this issue vacuuming aggressively and taking the performance hit that comes with it?

Thanks for any responses in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have understood the situation correctly.

You either need to make autovacuum more aggressive, or you need to use fewer temporary tables.

Unfortunately you cannot change the storage parameters on a catalog table – at least not in a supported fashion that will survive an upgrade – so you will have to do so for the whole cluster.

Comment: I was scratching my head looking at your answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366509/temporary-tables-bloating-pg-attribute) trying to figure out why that would help because I didn't think it would, but I think in his case you were suggesting he essentially lowers the amount of temporary tables used through that instead. Guess I'll have to just rewrite the whole thing to work differently. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Well, if you are on 9.6 and didn't change your autovacuum configuration, you'll be running with `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = '20ms'`, which pretty high. Perhaps lowering it to 2ms will be enough to make your system function.